# Нейросетевой синтез речи python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, синтезатор-речи

Мне нужно сделать нейросеть для синтеза речи, обучающуюся на mp3 записях голоса и иметь возможность импорта её в уже сделанный голосовой помощник. Пробовал рыться в Libros`е, но без единого понятия как вместо списков воткнуть в неё числа от спектрограммы. Какие библиотеки/сайты/посты/треды/ смогут мне в этом помочь?

Comment: Без понимания, как это всё вообще работает, лучше за это не браться. Сначала поразбирайтесь, как вообще эти нейросети работают, как их тренируют, на каких данных и т.д. Вы можете свою нейросеть обучить на тех данных, которые у вас есть, но вы должны понимать, что вы вообще делаете, а не просто пытаться скормить в готовый алгоритм хоть что-нибудь.